# How to use flex box to have BS4 nav-item fill navbar height with text centered vertically

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to customize a bootstrap 4 navbar. I want the nav-items to fill the full height of the navbar div while keeping their contents centered vertically and the spacing between the 3 horizontally links consistent (using justify-content-around). I have not been successful using the code below. Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-primary pt-0 pb-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-sm-block mr-auto my-2" href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/139x60"></a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mx-5" id="navbarCollapse">

    <!-- Stetch these virticall -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 align-items-start">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link bg-danger" href="#">Shop Now<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Why Buy From Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 mr-auto mr-sm-0 mx-md-auto">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-search"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please provide the css.

Comment: I'm using the core BS4.4.1 minified css.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in order to get bootstrap navbar links to fill the full height of the navbar and center the text vertically, I needed to add a targetable container inside the .nav-link class to apply align-self: center to.

I used a span tag and decided to use CSS rather than inline classes to keep the code cleaner and in my case limited it to only the #mainNav ID.

Wondering if there is an even cleaner way to do this without the extra span tag.

```css
#mainNav,
.collapse,
.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

#mainNav .nav-item {
  display: flex;
}

#mainNav .nav-link span {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>full height nav</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark text-white bg-primary justify-content-sm-end">
      <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex align-items-end">
        <li class="nav-item d-sm-none">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Company Name</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product Registration</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-block">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light pt-0 pb-0">
      <!-- Logo -->
      <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-sm-block my-2 order-md-first" href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/139x60.png?text=LOGO">
      </a>
      <!-- Search Bar -->
      <form class="form-inline order-md-last m-0">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- Toggler -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mx-5" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span>Shop Now</span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span>Why Company</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span>Buying Guide</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add class "my-0 p-0" in your brand image

Then, add approximately "height: 3.7em" to your links and add the "py-3" class to them